# How can I solve the curve integral of $\frac{cos(z)}{z^2}$ with the unit circle as curve?

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried to make a partial fraction decomposition but that didn't work. Can someone show me how to do it with the residue theorem?

Comment: What are the poles and residues? Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: $\cos(z)/z^2$ is even.

Comment: There is a double pole at z = 0 and I think the residue is 0. (it's the first time I try to use this theorem)

Answer (score 2):

By Cauchy's integral formula:
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{1!}\cos'(0)=0$$
where $\gamma$ is the unit circle curve.